# SPI kernel module, how to istantiate the driver?

Tags: kernel-module, spi

I've been tasked to import the spi driver into an existing platform running Openwrt.
After  "successfully" build the full Openwrt: packages and the kernel matching the one running into the platform, including the spidev kernel module I run into some trouble in make this module work.
**insmod** of the driver terminates without error, and I see that in the **/sys/class** the creation of the directory **spidev**, but it is empty.
Looking at the code of the spidev kernel module, the function **probe** has caught my eye. My feel is that this function is what actually allocates the minor device number an make the device available to be used. But it's not clear to me who, or what should call it.
Another doubt I have is about the architecture. The spi depends on the underlaying architecture, which in my case is the MT7620 soc which is a mipsel architecture have a specific spi code. In my understanding this SOC specific code is wrapped by the spidev kernel module and the link between these two entities should be

```
status = spi_register_driver(&spidev_spi_driver);
```

in the

```
static int __init spidev_init(void)
```

function.
Again, I'm far to be sure of what I'm writing and I'm here asking for directions.

Comment: `spidev` is a **raw** driver to SPI bus. What you need to look is some drivers that are using `module_spi_driver()` macro.

Comment: Issue is still open by my side. I want to thank you to have casted some light in my lack of knowledge. I suspected spidev was not exactly what I were looking for. googling around I found some other piece of code which contains code that seem to be more specific regarding my platform. So said, the code I found does not have any init function so I wonder how could it work. By the way, the module obtained by its compilation, can be insmod without error, but it doesn't seem to produce any visible effect. Is there any dependence among spi modules (eg. with spidev.ko) to get them work?

Answer (score 1):

First, you may want to read the [Linux Device Driver - Chapter 14](https://static.lwn.net/images/pdf/LDD3/ch14.pdf).

Generally speaking, in the Linux kernel you have `devices` and `drivers` on a `bus` (`subsystem`). You have to register them using the functions `register_device()` and `register_driver()` (the exact name depends on the subsystem). When a device or a driver get registered the `subsystem` will try to match `devices` with `drivers`. If they match, the `subsystem` calls the driver's function `probe()`. So, the execution of the `probe()` function can be triggered by the driver registration or the device registration. This also means that the device exists before the execution of `probe()`

Back to your specific case: SPI. To register a device instance you need to use [spi_alloc_device](https://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/latest/source/include/linux/spi/spi.h#L1339) and [spi_add_device](https://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/latest/source/include/linux/spi/spi.h#L1342), or [spi_new_device](https://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/latest/source/include/linux/spi/spi.h#L1345). Where to put this code? This depends on your need. Typically, the SPI devices are declared in some architecture file or device-tree description. Probably you can also do it in a module (not sure).

The `spidev` is a Linux device driver that exports the SPI raw interface to the user-space. This means that once you register an SPI device instance the driver `spidev` take control of it. Actually, the `spidev` does nothing: it waits for an user-space program to read/write data on the SPI bus. So, you will end up writing the driver for your device in userspace.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It is quite obvious I'm trying to do something I'm not yet qualified to do. But that's the essence of learning something new. Now, I read carefully your answer but, because my poor knowledge on the argument, I couldn't extract anything useful. Is spidev a module wrapper? something that needs the actual hardware related code? If so in which way are they related? do I need to have further kernel module to hope make this hardware work?

Comment: I updated the question with what is related to the SPI topic. Then you are asking questions about the Linux device driver model which are better answered on the Linux Device Driver book.
As you said, you have a lack of knowledge about the topic: I really suggest you to read the book. An answer on stackoverflow  can't give you an exhaustive answer.

Answer (score 0):

First are we talking about SPI controller driver or SPI device driver?
I assume the latter.

In short `spidev` is just a userspace interface, a character device driver which is not aware of any underlying protocol.

`spidev` doesn't and cant recognize device it is communicating with, it doesn't know if it is FLASH, CODEC, EEPROM and is not protocol aware, it doesn't understand if data part it handles in address, opcode or data.

You need a specific kernel driver for your specific SPI device.

And kernel will try to match your driver with device by device-tree **compatible** property of device tree SPI node:

```
.compatible = "tcg,tpm_tis-spi"n
```

And if it makes a match it will then call `probe()` function inside driver which
will initialize driver and device with data supplied in device tree SPI node.

And try to communicate with the device itself, read out ID registers to further identify device, because this driver knows the protocol used by this device.